# Does JSSoup support select() similar to Beautiful Soup or JSoup?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jssoup

Does [JSSoup](https://github.com/chishui/JSSoup) (which itself states "*JavaScript + BeautifulSoup = JSSoup*") support a `select()` operation similar to [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to select elements based on a CSS selector?

I did not find it, does it probably exist with a different name?

Comment: Maybe, since you are using native js, you could use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I have a string that contains HTML which I want to analyze, not the page's DOM itself.

Comment: **Note:** _[Naming Style](https://github.com/chishui/JSSoup#naming-style): JSSoup tries to use the same interfaces as BeautifulSoup so BeautifulSoup user can use JSSoup seamlessly. However, JSSoup uses Javascript's camelCase naming style instead of Python's underscore naming style. Such as `find_all()` in BeautifulSoup is replaced as `findAll()`._

Comment: Now JSSoup supports select() for CSS selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to utilize selector querying similar to `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`.

Here is the `findAll` definition in JSsoup:

```js
{
  key: 'findAll',
  value: function findAll() {
    var name = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : undefined;
    var attrs = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : undefined;
    var string = arguments.length > 2 && arguments[2] !== undefined ? arguments[2] : undefined;
    // ...
    var strainer = new SoupStrainer(name, attrs, string);
    // ...
  }
}
```

And here is the `SoupStrainer` constructor:

```js
function SoupStrainer(name, attrs, string) {
  _classCallCheck(this, SoupStrainer);

  if (typeof attrs == 'string') {
    attrs = { class: [attrs] };
  } else if (Array.isArray(attrs)) {
    attrs = { class: attrs };
  } else if (attrs && attrs.class && typeof attrs.class == 'string') {
    attrs.class = [attrs.class];
  }
  if (attrs && attrs.class) {
    for (var i = 0; i < attrs.class.length; ++i) {
      attrs.class[i] = attrs.class[i].trim();
    }
  }
  this.name = name;
  this.attrs = attrs;
  this.string = string;
  }
```

You are required to pass a tag name as the first argument, followed by attributes. A string is treated as a class name.

### Example usage

```js
const JSSoup = require('jssoup').default;

const html = `
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p class="foo">First</p>
    <p class="foo bar">Second</p>
    <div class="foo">Third</div>
  </body>
</html>
`;

const printTags = (tags) => console.log(tags.map(t => t.toString()).join(' '));

const soup = new JSSoup(html);

printTags(soup.findAll('p', 'foo'));
// <p class="foo">First</p> <p class="foo">Second</p>

printTags(soup.findAll('p', { class: 'foo' }));
// <p class="foo">First</p> <p class="foo">Second</p>

printTags(soup.findAll('p', { class: 'foo' }, 'Second'));
// <p class="foo">Second</p>

printTags(soup.findAll('p', { class: ['foo', 'bar'] }));
// <p class="foo">Second</p>

printTags(soup.findAll(null, 'bar'));
// <p class="foo bar">Second</p> <div class="foo">Third</div>
```

Comment: @MarkusWeninger Added a `null` (wildcard) tag name example at the very bottom.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, it appears to be called [`find`](https://github.com/chishui/JSSoup#find) or [`findAll`](https://github.com/chishui/JSSoup#findall) depending on whether you want to find one or many. Here's an example they give:

```
var data = `
<div>
  <p> hello </p>
  <p> world </p>
</div>
`
var soup = new JSSoup(data);
soup.find('p')
// <p> hello </p>
```

[Looking at the source](https://github.com/chishui/JSSoup/blob/master/lib/jssoup.js), I don't see anything offering CSS selector functionality, but it did show that `find` and `findAll` accept more than one argument, and an example in [the documentation for BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree) shows using the second argument to filter by class, e.g.:

```
const JSSoup = require('jssoup').default;
const data = `
<div>
    <p class="foo bar"> hello </p>
    <p> world </p>
</div>
`
const soup = new JSSoup(data);
console.log(soup.find('p', 'foo').toString()); // Logs: <p class="foo bar">hello</p>
```

The second argument can be used for other attributes as well, but CSS selectors don't seem to be an option.

You have other options, such as [`jsdom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom), which has all the usual DOM stuff such as `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`:

```
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const data = `
<div>
    <p class="foo bar"> hello </p>
    <p> world </p>
</div>
`;
const dom = new JSDOM(data);
const doc = dom.window.document;
console.log(doc.querySelector(".foo").outerHTML); // Logs: <p class="foo bar"> hello </p>
```

Comment: This seems to work only with tag names, but for example not with CSS classes. For example `mySoup.findAll('.myClass')` does return an empty array, even though I have elements with the class `myClass`.

Comment: @MarkusWeninger - Looks like it's *slightly* more than just tag name, but yeah, not full CSS selectors. I wouldn't like to use this API. :-) I'd probably go for [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) or similar, which has `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the hint with _jsdom_!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the already given answers, I just want to add: One can also just search by class name (without a tag name) by setting the tag name to `undefined` in `find()` and `findAll()`:

```
mySoup.findAll(undefined, 'myClass');
```